# Can't Get Authorized Using ADAL Auth Flow

Tags: python, azure-functions, adal, power-automate

I'm writing an Azure Function app in Python that needs to access an API: `https://service.flow.microsoft.com/`
I keep getting a `401 Unauthorized` response. I can access other resources using this same configuration, such as `https://contoso.crm.dynamics.com`, which leads me to believe the ServiceURL, ClientID, and ClientSecret are all correct. The app has the required permissions in Azure AD.

```
authContext = AuthenticationContext(os.environ["ServiceUrl"])
token = authContext.acquire_token_with_client_credentials(
    "https://service.flow.microsoft.com/", os.environ["ClientID"], os.environ["ClientSecret"])

headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + token["accessToken"],
    "OData-MaxVersion": "4.0",
    "OData-Version": "4.0",
    "Accept": "application/json"
}

apiUrl = f"https://api.flow.microsoft.com/providers/Microsoft.ProcessSimple/environments/{flow['environmentid']}/flows/{flow['RowKey']}/runs?api-version=2016-11-01&$orderby=startTime"

response = request("GET", apiUrl, headers=headers)
```

API Permissions in AD:

[image]

Tried using the common tenant ID in the service URL, still failed. I am able to connect using the common tenant ID and a user authentication flow in a local setting, but that is not possible when this is run serverless in Azure. I also tried playing with MSAL but couldn't get that to work either.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to change the Authorization level to Anonymous.
`"authLevel": "anonymous"`

Check for iss claim i.e; **issuer url** in token after decoding , see if it is **v1** endpoint and change the same in the manifest `accesstokenacceptedversion` to 1.else if it is v2  change to v2.
Also check for the aud i.e audience claim which has to match the client id .

To call the Azure REST API, you need to **add a scope** for api.
In portal if have given **api permission s**omething like `user_impersonation`  and **exposed an api** to that permission.

`Ex:  api://<clientId>/user_impersonation` (appIdUri/scope)
Your scope can be `scope = api://<clientId>/user_impersonation` or you can  try `api://<clientId>/.default`

If the api is *graph api* , scope can be https://graph.microsoft.com/.default

Ex : [python-azure-identity-clientsecretcredential](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66398527/python-azure-identity-clientsecretcredential/66417556#66417556)

```
scope = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
token = credential.get_token(scope)
```

**References:**

1. [python 3.x - How to properly use "get_token" of
   "ManagedIdentityCredential" of azure identity - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66414605/how-to-properly-use-get-token-of-managedidentitycredential-of-azure-identity?msclkid=69738a9fab4e11eca2057d21a8911630)
2. [GitHub - Azure-Samples Python Azure Function Web API secured by Azure AD](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-webapi-azurefunctions?msclkid=6971d5e1ab4e11ec97f4c64614e0d28b)  / [Python Azure code sample | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/ms-identity-python-webapi-azurefunctions/ms-identity-python-webapi-azurefunctions/?msclkid=3ee521c8ab5011ec8d1f3c949cb8749a)
3. [c# - Azure Function with AD auth results in 401 Unauthorized when
   using Bearer tokens - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55226143/azure-function-with-ad-auth-results-in-401-unauthorized-when-using-bearer-tokens?msclkid=589ed472ab4a11ec987bb0043d55c409)